# Proving by induction that $\sum\limits_{k=2}^n \frac1{k^2}\le 1$

Tags: inequality, induction, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble proving this by induction. We need to show that $P(k+1)$ is true: $$\sum_{i=2}^{k+1} \frac{1}{i^2}\leq 1.$$

Don't know where to go from here. Any help?

Comment: Chance Gordon, I have edited your question to be more readable. Please ensure it is what you wanted to ask.

Comment: @Clayton yup, thats what I'm looking for.

Comment: Induction is usually a bad choice for proving inequalities. Why not bound it by a telescoping sum? ( Hint: $\frac{1}{i^2} \le \frac{1}{i(i-1)} = \frac{1}{i-1} - \frac{1}{i}$ ).

Comment: @achillehui I'm not sure how to go about that method

Comment: A visual proof: https://www.facebook.com/ArtOfMathematics/photos/a.152024481885601.1073741828.151575005263882/214900522264663/?type=3&theater

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Try to apply induction to
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n \frac1{k^2}\le 1-\frac1{n},\qquad n\ge2.
$$

Comment: But doesn't that break the inequality?

Comment: On the contrary, it makes it easy to prove the inductive step...

Comment: Am I allowed to do so? Because then I'm proving a different function which I'm not supposed to do..

Comment: Yeah. If you can prove that the sum is less than $1 - \frac{1}{n}$, it is automatically less than $1$ and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Note: NOT a proof by induction as demanded

Let,the whole big square represent $1$ and the smaller parts inside the terms of the series $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^2},\frac{1}{3^2},\frac{1}{4^2},...$

[image]

Special thanks to @Alex.Jordan and @ArtOfMathematics

Comment: That's a great picture, but how is it a proof by induction?

Comment: @Théophile No its not by induction...but still great one...so posted it...